# Error al iniciar el servidor IBM Websphere Application Server V8.5

Tags: jvm, websphere

He estado un tiempo trabajando con este servidor y versiones antiguas, es cierto que este me ha fallado de vez en cuando sin razón aparente pero con reiniciarlo era suficiente para que volviese a correr con normalidad. El caso es que ayer volví a poner como argumento genérico el "-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8" y al reiniciarlo para que los cambios surtiesen efecto empezó a lanzarme el siguiente mensaje (lo resaltado en amarillo):[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar mientras yo sigo investigando también. Si lo solucionase os envío la respuesta.

1.- He estado mirando el archivo que dice el mensaje para visualizar el error, al igual que ayer tarde no veo nada y es debido a que no se actualiza, se ve que el error también esta perjudicando a este archivo y no registra nada desde ayer por la tarde cuando lo paré para reiniciarlo y que tuviese efecto lo del argumento de JVM.

Comment: Imagino que agregaste el argumento desde la [consola de administración](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21673998). ¿Se ha agregado correctamente en el archivo [server.xml](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21673998)?

Comment: Vale @PaulVargas si fue por consola administrativa, muchas gracias, voy a mirar, pero me aparecen varios archivos server.xml en Websphere, en cual debo mirar? Estuve mirando por internet concretamente esto también (al imaginar que lo que tocases en la consola administrativa se debería registrar en algún archivo de la carpeta) pero tampoco encontré nada, quizás de con la solución a raíz de aquí, voy a ir mirándolos todos hasta que me contestes, si lo soluciono antes aviso. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @PaulVargas no se si está bien visto el tipo de respuesta que acabo de dar cuando lo he solucionado gracias a ti, si quieres editar, mejorar o que la borre y la añadas tu por mi encantado. A fin de cuentas diste con el quebradero de cabeza que tuve todo el viernes que fue buscar ese maldito archivo (que era totalmente desconocido para mí) Gracias de nuevo y quedo a la espera de lo que más te complazca amigo :)

Comment: ¡Qué bien! No fue nada. Pienso que la respuesta que has puesto es adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución estaba en intentar buscar el archivo en el cual se registraba lo tocado en la consola administrativa, concretamente lo que toqué fue lo del argumento genérico jvm y me olía a que me había comido el guión, no pensaba que ese pudiese ser el problema pero efectivamente así lo fue. Gracias al comentario de @PaulVargas por localizar el archivo donde debería mirar si estaba todo correcto ví que le faltaba el guión al argumento: Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8.

El archivo server.xml que hay que tocar se encuentra en la siguiente ruta:

[nuestrarutalocal]\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\config\cells\por003016Node01Cell\nodes\por003016Node01\servers\server1 y una vez abierto buscamos: genericJvmArguments en el archivo, comprobamos que contenga lo siguiente: genericJvmArguments="-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8". Como digo le faltaba el guión y me daba el error que presento arriba.

Si alguna vez os sucede algo parecido aquí tenéis la solución pero pensar que pueda deberse a cualquier otro tipo de añadidura que hagáis, no creo que sea un problema específico del argumento genérico, espero que pueda servir de ayuda en un futuro a alguien con el mismo problema que yo. Saludos.